# Report weight from row in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R who got this question:

> One of the functions we will be using often is sample(). Read the help file for sample() using ?sample. Now take a random sample of size 1 from the numbers 13 to 24 and report back the weight of the mouse represented by that row. Make sure to type set.seed(1) to ensure that everybody gets the same answer.

I tried this:

```
set.seed(1)
i <- sample( 13:24, 1)
dat$Bodyweight[i]
```

And got the answer `25.34`. But apparently, that's wrong. What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Per the description of the assignment, I believe your code is correct. What does `dat` look like? What is the correct answer? What is the *source* of that correct answer? Is there any other code being executed between `set.seed(1)` and `i <- sample(..)`?

Comment: @r2evans I do not know the correct answer, no other code is being executed

Comment: If this is an automated answer-checker, they often give false-negatives when the necessary number of digits are not shown. For instance, the answer might be `25.341`. Try `options(digits=5)` (or 6) and check again. The checker really *should* tell you if it's looking for *"n digits"* in the reply.

Answer (score 0):

you need to detect which col u want to choose from first

```
set.seed(1)
sample(data$Bodyweight[13:24] ,1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(1)
i <- sample( 13:24, 1)
dat$Bodyweight[i]
```

A = 34.02

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.